# Sharepoint: Submitted Items (Forms) in multiple lists

Tags: list, form, item

I want to create a simple SharePoint site where:

1) A page form to submit items

2) items submitted from (1) will be displayed in multiple List pages with different Group By's.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Did you find an answer for your question? If yes, can you post it please? It would be useful